# how to resolve dependency tree typeorm and nestjs during node modules installation

Tags: nestjs, node-modules

During installation of a Nest Application node modules, I have the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ticket-be@0.1.3
npm ERR! Found: typeorm@0.2.45
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
npm ERR!   typeorm@"^0.2.45" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typeorm@"^0.2.25" from @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@0.30.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs-query/query-typeorm
npm ERR!     @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@"^0.30.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!   @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.0" from @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@0.30.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs-query/query-typeorm
npm ERR!     @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@"^0.30.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Can you give me suggestions to resolve dependency? Or is better to use --force or --legacy-peer-deps?
Thank you in advance.

Here dependencies section of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.6.1",
    "@nestjs-query/query-typeorm": "^0.30.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.4",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.1",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "fastify-swagger": "^5.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "swagger-themes": "^1.2.22",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.45",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.72.1"
  }
```

I tried to remove "typeorm": "^0.2.45" from package.json, but I have same type error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: ticket-be@0.1.3
npm ERR! Found: typeorm@0.3.10
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
npm ERR!   peer typeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!     @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.0" from @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@0.30.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@nestjs-query/query-typeorm
npm ERR!       @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@"^0.30.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typeorm@"^0.2.25" from @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@0.30.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs-query/query-typeorm
npm ERR!   @nestjs-query/query-typeorm@"^0.30.0" from the root project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4` requires that you use `typeorm@^0.3.0` but `@nestjs-query/query-typeorm@"^0.30.0"` requires that you use `typeorm@^0.2.25`. You need to downgrade `@nestjs/typeorm` to something that is compatible with `@nestjs-query/query-typeorm` or upgrade `@nestjs-query/query-typeorm` to something that has a compatible typeorm version with `@nestjs/typeorm@^8.1.4`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this tip still works today, their latest packages are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed version:

`"@nestjs/typeorm": "8.0.3"`

and now it works, thanks @jay-mcdoniel